# WildFly 8.2 and 304 Not Modified

Tags: java, http, jboss, wildfly

RFC 2616 - "All 1xx (informational), 204 (no content), and 304 (not modified) responses MUST NOT include a message-body."

After upgrading to WildFly 8.2 from JBoss 5.1, load balancer (written with Netty 4.0) broke.

Cause - WildFly sends response with message-body on 304 error:

```
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Not Modified</body></html>
```

Netty in accordance with RFC 2616 reads only header for 304, but ignore not zero Content-Length and left body in socket, so we get error on second read from same channel.

I can fix that by changing response.sendError(304) to response.setStatus(304), but want to know, is that possible to configure WildFly to not send message-body on 304 Not Modified error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, 2xx and 3xx are *not* errors. Only response codes in the ranges 4xx and 5xx are errors (client errors and server errors, respectively). So, I'd argue that `setStatus` is indeed the correct one.

As you are telling the server that you are sending an error, but not including a body, the server is including one itself. This is because errors (4xx and 5xx) have this requirement:

> Except when responding to a HEAD request, the
>      server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the
>      error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent
>      condition.